# Attachments that created by "attachfile2" can't be opened, but can be by "attachfile" in LaTeX, which is caused by "XeLaTeX"

Tags: chinese, ctex, attachfile

With `attachfile` package, the PDF file can contain the attachment that can be opened by double clicking. But with `attachfile2` package and `ctex` package, it can't. Sometimes, `attachfile` can't be replaced by `attachfile2`, as `attachfile` doesn't support the **XeLaTeX** engine and `ctex` package, which sometimes must be used.

With `attachfile` package:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{attachfile}
\begin{document}  
\textattachfile{22.pdf}{\textcolor{blue}{\LaTeX\ Sourcecode}}
\end{document}
```

will output:

[image]

Double click the blue frame will open the **22.pdf**.

If use `attachfile2` package and `ctex` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{attachfile2,ctex}
\begin{document}
 \textattachfile{22.pdf}{view source code}
\end{document}
```

If used **pdfLaTeX**, all things are right. But if use **XeLaTeX**, we will get the file, which only seems all right, as when double click the link in the PDF file, we will get the error:

[image]

So, I guess it is caused by incompatibility of **XeLaTeX** and `attachfile2` package.

Comment: `\usepackage[xetex]{attachfile2}` maybe, it says in the [documentation (p. 3)](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/attachfile2/attachfile2.pdf)

Comment: @JamesT Thanks. Using this way will output a file, in which the link isn't clickable. Maybe I used **XeLaTeX** engine whereas used `xetex` option.

Comment: there is a fix at the github version, I should sent it to ctan. For now do `\textattachfile[ucfilespec=22.pdf]{22.pdf}{...}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This option seems not work right. There is an error `! Package keyval Error: ucfilespec undefined.`

Comment: then your package version is too old.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  But I had just updated all my packages a few minutes before.

Comment: check in the log-file which version you are using.

Comment: that is attachfile, not attachfile2.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  Yes. You are right. I used the wrong package (`attachfile`). Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  But I have another question. The `ucfilespec` is for **file names with characters outside ASCII**, but this PDF file name is **22.pdf**, which should be inside the ASCII. Why should I add this specifier.

Comment: because it works around the problem. see also https://github.com/ho-tex/attachfile2/issues/5

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Okay. I just can't understand it.